Compatibility of Rust and BPF target
Encountering issues when trying to add the bpfel-unknown-unknown target for your Rust setup to develop Solana programs. The main problem seems to stem from the fact that you're still using the stable Rust toolchain in your project directory, which does not support the BPF target? same happens when i install the nightly version.... can i get help.
Thank you!

Solana uses the rust version from the plattform tools that get installed when you install the solana tool chain. You can find it on the cache folder on mac:
/Users/user/.cache/solana
https://docs.solanalabs.com/de/cli/install
Solana 'build-bpf` is deprecated, try install a newer version of solana and use 'cargo build-sbf' instead.
